# How to convert string into array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a data shown below but it is of string type

```
  "[
     {
      name: "Robert Baratheon",
      birthday: "12/02/1965"
    }, {
      name: "Daario Naharis",
      birthday: "12/02/1985"
    }, {
      name: "Viserys Targaryen",
      birthday: "12/06/1984"
    }
  ]"
```

I want to convert it into array of objects, but when i use `JSON.parse` or `eval` then it is giving me something like this

```
[Object, Object, Object]
```

but i don't want like this, i just want to remove its double quotes like so i can access it like array.

```
   [
    {
      name: "Robert Baratheon",
      birthday: "12/02/1965"
    }, {
      name: "Daario Naharis",
      birthday: "12/02/1985"
    }, {
      name: "Viserys Targaryen",
      birthday: "12/06/1984"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(string)` does the same thing. You can't remove string delimiters.

Comment: It is an array only and you can use it the way you want it to. `[Object, Object, Object]` is an array only.

Comment: I'm guessing your using console.log to get the Object, Object, Object output? That's what console write when it's got an object. Apart from that it's very unclear what your trying to achieve?

Comment: Click on the `object` and you will see all data. The console hides the data.

Comment: "then it is giving me something like this" — It does then when you try to convert it to a string. Don't convert it to a string and you can "access it like array" because after passing it through JSON.parse it will be an array.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `JSON.parse(string)` you will in fact parse a string of JSON into an Object. In your case, an array of objects.

You can access this object via

```
var myList = JSON.parse(string)
myList[0] //This will give you the first item in the list
console.log(myList[0].name) //Outputs Robert Baratheon to the console
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want like this?

```
var json = JSON.parse(string);
var length = json.length;
var names = [];
var birthdays = [];
for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
{
  names[i] = json[i].name;
  birthdays[i] = json[i].birthday;
}
console.log(names);
console.log(birthdays);
```